# изменения шрифта, или фона элемента списка после редактирования(или клика) JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Друзья, задача довольно простая, но никак не могу реализовать ее. Необходимо изменить шрифт, или фон элемента списка после редактирования(или клика) на React, JS. Возможно можно как-то достучаться к элементу списка

через dom дерево? У меня что-то не выходит :(
Прошу помощи
фрагмент кода:

```
 function changeBackground(e) {
  document.querySelector("elementUserCard");
  e.current.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

return(
...
          <ul>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <li
              //   onClick={() => changeBackground()}
              className={s.elementUserCard}
              key={user.id}
            >
              <User user={user} />
              <div className={s.buttonContainer}>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteUserById(user.id)}>
                  Delete
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={(e) => toggleModal(user)}>
                  Edit
                </button>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас className задан через импортированные стили `s.elementUserCard`, а это значит что у него будет свой уникальный идентификатор (рандомный набор букаф). Именно по этой причине вы не можете до него достучаться (`document.querySelector("elementUserCard");`)

Решение (ЭТО ПСЕВДОКОД):
Тебе нужно создать локальный стейт твоего заднего фона. При клике мы будем проверять его предыдущее значение и ставить новое, в зависимости от старого.

```
const [color, setColor] = useState('black');

function changeBackground() {
  setColor((prevState) => (prevState === 'black' ? 'white' : 'black'));
}

return(
...
          <ul>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <li
              onClick={() => changeBackground()}
              className={[{backgroundColor: color}, s.elementUserCard}]}
              key={user.id}
            >
              <User user={user} />
              <div className={s.buttonContainer}>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteUserById(user.id)}>
                  Delete
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={(e) => toggleModal(user)}>
                  Edit
                </button>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!